# Several images in one XMLFILE using XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like these :

```
SELECT a.test AS 'TRANSFERT/STUFF/NAME", b.URL AS "TRANSFERT/STUFF/IMAGE/URL"
FROM stuff a, image b
WHERE a.id = b.id
FOR XML PATH;
```

But I can have several images for the same stuff.

And what I want is an xml like these :

```
<TRANSFERT>
<STUFF>CAR</STUFF>
<IMAGE>http://url1</IMAGE>
<IMAGE>http://url2</IMAGE>
<IMAGE>http://url3</IMAGE>
</TRANSFERT>
```

How can I have an xml file like this ?

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a nested query with XML to achieve your desired result, e.g.:

```sql
-- Database setup...
create table dbo.[stuff] (
  id int not null,
  test nvarchar(10)
);
insert dbo.[stuff] (id, test) values
    (1, N'CAR');

create table dbo.[image] (
  id int not null,
  [URL] nvarchar(20)
);
insert dbo.[image] (id, [URL]) values
    (1, N'http://url1'),
    (1, N'http://url2'),
    (1, N'http://url3');

-- XML query result...
select
    a.test as 'STUFF',
    (
        select [URL] as 'text()'
        from dbo.[image] b
        where b.id = a.id
        for xml path('IMAGE'), type
    )
from dbo.[stuff] a
for xml path('TRANSFERT');
```

Which yields the result...

```xml
<TRANSFERT>
  <STUFF>CAR</STUFF>
  <IMAGE>http://url1</IMAGE>
  <IMAGE>http://url2</IMAGE>
  <IMAGE>http://url3</IMAGE>
</TRANSFERT>
```